# how to make Ui same like screen

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How can I make a layout like this screen shot, with text left and right of the flower image:

[image]

This is what I tried so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bitmapstrech"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/logostar" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bitmap"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="San Diego Unified"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to add one more element to get this thing working like on the picture.

Try this hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: @user2725048 SO is not to spoonfeed.. Try yourself ..Answer is self explanatory +1

Comment: @user2725048 i guess, firstly you need to look at this for a while http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
     <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#696969"
    android:background="@drawable/bitmapstrech" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </ImageView>


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/logostar" >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="San Diego Unified"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >        
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```